# How OS understand what data for what thread?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I can figure out how OS understand which data for which thread?
For example thread/process `A` send request to DB, then scheduler switch on process `B`. But when data is coming (answer from DB/FS or whatever) CPU run process `C`.

How OS understand who is owner of data? Where they are storing before OS will send them to proper thread?

Comment: I gave an answer with several references, but your question is very confusing and too broad. You need to read several books. We cannot teach you all that in some answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entire book is needed to answer your question. So read [Operating Systems: three easy pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

You want to learn more about [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

If using Linux, read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). See also the list of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

The [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (often, its [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29)) is managing data, [virtual address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), and [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (and [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)), so is bookkeeping a lot of meta data about them, notably their owner. The very notion of owner is provided by the OS (at the hardware level, that notion does not exist; but read about [CPU modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes)). For Linux, see also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), etc...